# what is the best approach to keep two kafka clusters in Sync

Tags: apache-kafka

I have to setup two kafka clusters in two different data centers (DCs), which have same topics and configuration. the reason is that the connectivity between two data centers is nasty we cannot create a global one.

We are having producers and consumers to publish and subcribe to the topics of each DC.

the problem is that I need to keep both clusters in sync.
Lets say: all messages are written to the first DC should be eventually replicated to the second, and otherway around.

I am evaluation the kafka MirrorMaker tool by creating the Mirror by consuming messages of the first and procuding messages to the second one. However it is also requried to replicate data from the second to the first because writing data is both allowed in two clusters.

I dont think the Kafka MirrorMaker tool is fit to our case. 
Appricate any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://www.confluent.io/blog/enterprise-streaming-multi-datacenter-replication-apache-kafka/ which might be a help.

Comment: Thanks @amethystic for your advice,but it is not realy our case.
 My situation is that we have an application run in two different DCs backed by two Kafka clusters. both are playing active modes (not master slave model) means if a message consumed by instance in one DC, it wil be replicated to another one but not processed by same instance type. Have you got any idea for this? I am stucking with  issue, How can we identify messages procesed in one DC, will not be processed in another one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on your exact requirements, you can use MirrorMaker for your use case.

One option would be to just have two separate topics, lets call them topic1 on cluster 1 and topic2 on cluster 2. All your producing threads write to the "local" topic and you use mirrormaker to replicate this topic to the remote cluster.

For your consumers, you simply subscribe to both topics on whatever cluster is closest to you, that way you will get all records that were written on either cluster.
I have created an illustration that hopefully helps:

[image]

Alternatively, you could create aggregation topics on both clusters and use MirrorMaker to replicate data into this topic, this would enable you to have all data in one topic for consumption.
You would have duplicate data on the same cluster this way, but you could take care of this by lower retention settings on the input topic.
Again, hopefully the following picture helps to explains my thinking:
[image]
In order for this to work, you will need to configure MirrorMaker to replicate a topic into a topic with a different name, which is not a standard thing for it to do, I have written a small [blog post](http://www.opencore.com/blog/2017/1/170131-mirrormaker-change-topic/) on how to do this, if you want to investigate this option further.

Comment: Thanks @sönke-liebau for your articulate explaination. It is resoved problem with replication between two DCs. 

However, we are having an application deployed in multiple regions. How can I know that one a message processed by an instance  in DC1, will not be processed same instance type in DC2, assuming all services are stateless. 

Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Hi @Van, just to be sure I understand you correctly, what you want to do is process all messages (staying with the example above - the topic "Sales_All") distributed across both DCs while making sure that no messages gets processed twice?

Comment: Yes, it is my intention

Comment: That is actually a very hard thing to do and to be quite honest, I think you should reconsider you architecture and try to come up with a solution that circumvents this issue before heading down this road!

Basically I can think of two ways to do this:

Come up with some sort of partitioning strategy to distribute your data between the DCs ensure that processors in both DCs only work on messages that they are in charge of.

Alternatively you could create some sort of common system that keeps track of which message has been processed and which one has not (Zookeeper f.ex).

Comment: Thanks @sönke-liebau for your suggession. We will reconsider this way. Basically what we want to achieve is that building an application support multipe regions, so users in region can access to a single global data platform. I am not sure whether you can suggest the best pratice for this case study?

Comment: I'm sure we can come up with something sensible, yes. Could I ask that you open up a new question with all relevant details though?
Comments are very limited in length and are not the right place to answer full questions I think.